# GCP BQ - How to access public dataset in GCP console BQ Explorer

Tags: google-bigquery

It is possible to access a public dataset and table `firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282.events_20181001` in the GCP console of BigQuery Explorer?

```
bq show firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282.events_20181001 
---
Table firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282.events_20181001

   Last modified                     Schema                     Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Time Partitioning   Clustered Fields   Labels  
 ----------------- ------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------ ------------------- ------------------ -------- 
  27 Aug 05:10:28   |- event_date: string                       50000        36609581                                                                  
                    |- event_timestamp: integer                                                                                                        
                    |- event_name: string                                                                                                              
                    +- event_params: record (repeated)                                                                                                 
                    |  |- key: string                                                                                                                  
                    |  +- value: record                                                                                                                
                    |  |  |- string_value: string                                                                                                      
                    |  |  |- int_value: integer                                                                                                        
                    |  |  |- float_value: float                                                                                                        
                    |  |  |- double_value: float
```

The dataset table is publicly available. But searching it from the Search cannot find it.

[image]

Is there a way to be able to see and run queries against the table in the BQ Explorer console?

## Update

[image]

Comment: that's the search, use the `+Add data` button to pin a public project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above use `Add data > Pin a project > Enter a project name`

You will be able to visualize all the pinned projects in the BQ Explorer console and run queries from the UI.

Check the following page [Pinning a project](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#pinning_adding_a_project)